# How to use a handler function for two different purposes. SPFX (React/TypeScript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I am creating an SPFX form (react/Typescript).
I am using a handler function:

```
public handleChange = (evt: any) => {
    const {value} = (evt.target as any);

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [evt.target.name]: value
    });
  }
```

To handle multiple text fields.

What I want to do now is for this handler to cater for character count text fields. (I know I could have used labels!) These text fields count how many characters have been entered into each text field. I don't know how to write the code for this.
Below is what I've tried:

The handler function:

```
public handleChange = (evt: any) => {
    const {value} = (evt.target as any);

    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      [evt.target.name]: value
    }, () => {
      let wordCount = this.state.SOMETHING.toString().length; //This is wrong!
      this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        [evt.target.name]: wordCount
    });
  });
}
```

But as you can see I'm way off understanding what to put. As you can see with `wordCount` variable, I'm counting the amount of characters for the state of a textfield but this is obviously not going to work because I need it to cater for ALL of the textfields that run through the handler function. You can see also that I'm attempting to set this to state using the `[evt.target.name]: wordCount`, this I think is possibly closer to being correct. But not sure.

And if it helps, here are 2 textfields, one which is the user input text field and the other (below it) is the character counter:

```
  <td><TextField
        name="EssCrit1"
        value={this.state.EssCrit1}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        multiline rows={2}
     />
 </td>

   <td ><TextField 
        name="EssCritChars1"
        value={this.state.EssCritChars1}
        disabled={true}           
      />
 </td>
```

As you can see the character counter has it's own state but as mentioned above, how do i get the handler function to cater for that as well as the onChange event for the user input text field?

Any help would be great as always.

C

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the goal. Do you want to overwrite your state variable with the character count of the text entered? Or should it be separate?

Comment: I'm confused, do you want to count the characters in each field (the same value you'd get from `value.length`), or do you want to count the total of all the fields (like adding all the lengths)?

Comment: Side note: don't do `this.setState({...this.state, your stuff here })`. setState will already do that for your, all this does is risk updating with stale data. Just shorten to `this.setState({ your stuff here })`

Comment: Sorry chaps, I've added a bit more for understanding. Yes it was difficult to describe this one.

Comment: I think I'm more confused now

Comment: Brian: it should be separate.
Ricardo: I want to count the number of characters in each text field that the handler 'handles', but I know how to count the amount of chars, it's how I would implement that into the handler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to handle any given text field's value and the value's length:

```
public handleChange = (evt: any) => {
    const {value} = (evt.target as any);

    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: value,
      `${evt.target.name}Count`: value.toString.length,
    });
}
```

Comment: [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) is a function. `value.toString().length`

Comment: Hi Jimbot, your suggestion is not working for me. Red wavy line under [evt.target.name]: value saying this expression is not callable and Type '{ [x: number]: any; }' has no call signatures.

Comment: How would you handle any given drop downs value?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you could curry and add an additional parameter with the name of the corresponding counter to your onChange like this:

```js
<TextField
  name="EssCrit1"
  value={this.state.EssCrit1}
  onChange={this.handleChange('EssCritChars1')} // curry the name of the counter like this
  multiline rows={2}
/>

// We'll use counterName to update the correct counter state value
handleChange = (counterName: string) => (evt: any) => {
    const {value} = (evt.target as any);

    this.setState({
      [evt.target.name]: value
    }, () => {
      let wordCount = this.state[evt.target.name].toString().length; // Access as an array to use dynamic keys
      this.setState({
        [counterName]: wordCount // now we have a separate counter variable
    });
  });
}
```

Or, you could use an inline function with an optional second parameter like this:

```js
// Text field that has a counter
<TextField
  name="EssCrit1"
  value={this.state.EssCrit1}
  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, 'EssCritChars1')} // Inline. Pass event and name of counter
  multiline rows={2}
/>
// Text field that doesn't need a counter
<TextField
  name="another_field"
  value={this.state.another_field}
  onChange={this.handleChange} // We only need the event so don't bother creating an inline function
  multiline rows={2}
/>

// Second param is optional
handleChange = (evt: any, counter = '') => {
  const {value} = (evt.target as any);
  let newState = {
    [evt.target.name]: value
  }
  if (counter) {
    newState[counter] = value.toString().length
  }
  this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, newState });
}
```

Comment: Hi Brian, curry? :)

Comment: Hi Brian, I think I see what you are doing with your edits.

Comment: Its basically a function that returns a function. But shorthanded it looks like this `function(param)(other_param)` and called `myFunction()()`.

Comment: An alternative to currying would be to create inline functions for each input. `onChange={(e) => myHandleChange('EssCritChars1', e)}`. Then the function then becomes `myHandleChange = (counter, e) => {`

Comment: In your example above you have curried the name of the counter on the textfield, not the character counter textfield, is that intentional?

Comment: It was, but it was based on my understanding of your goal, so it might not be correct. What this function will do is set the value of `EssCrit1` to the entered text, and set the value of `EssCritChars1` to the character length of `EssCrit1`. Is that what you want it to do?

Comment: Hi Brian yes that's what I want. Unfortunately when adding the {this.handleChange('EssCritChars1')} it makes all the other fields require such a change. Should I go ahead and change them as some of the textfields don't need char counters.

Comment: No probably not. Since its not a requirement for all text fields I'd use the inline function way. I'll update my answer with that alternative

Comment: is JimBot's answer a simpler solution, or is it not suitable for my circumstance?

Comment: Simpler, yes. But it will store the count of every text field even for ones you dont need. Using an inline function and optional param isn't much more work and then you wont have extra values in state you dont need

Comment: I'm unable to enter text into the textfields in question. I commented out the this.setState(prevState =>... etc and this allowed me to enter text again, but of course this isn't updating state. Is ther something wrong with that last line?

Comment: Hi Brian, I just logged newState and it's receiving the first letter of what I type and the counter is counting 1, but no further than that. It seems that it's being overwritten as soon as something is typed into a textfield.

Comment: As Brian states, his solution is the better and more the efficient answer, but I have used JimBot's.