# How to create a handler function which 'handles' multiple textfields but also character counter textfields as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spfx

this is a continuation of:
[How to use a handler function for two different purposes. SPFX (React/TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649296/how-to-use-a-handler-function-for-two-different-purposes-spfx-react-typescript/59649478?noredirect=1#comment105461547_59649478)

which I've made a little progress from, so this isn't a duplicate, it's part 2 as it were.

My current code handler is:

```
  const {value} = (evt.target as any);
  const countKey = `${evt.target.name}Count`;
  const obj = {
    [evt.target.name]: value,
    [countKey]: value.toString().length,
  };
  this.setState({
    ...this.state,
   obj
}, () => { console.log(obj), console.log(countKey+'countKey'), console.log(value+'value');});
}
```

The render with the fields in question:

```
<td><TextField //THIS IS THE USER INPUT TEXTFIELD WHICH I WANT COUNTED BY THE TEXTFIELD BELOW!
        name="EssCrit1"
        value={this.state.EssCrit1}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        multiline rows={2}
        />
        </td>
        <td ><TextField //THIS IS THE CHARACTER COUNTER FIELD!
        name="EssCritChars1"
        value={this.state.EssCrit1Count}
        disabled={true} 
        />
     </td>
```

As you can see I'm logging obj and this is showing the correct textfield value typed in also it is counting how many characters. Problem is it doesn't allow text to be typed into the textfield. The value (EssCrit1) and the (EssCrit1Count) field seem to be registering the key press showing:

```
[object Object]: {EssCrit1: "h", EssCrit1Count: 1}
EssCrit1: "h"
EssCrit1Count: 1

__proto__: Object
```

in the console. But as mentioned it doesn't allow any text to be typed into the field. It seems as if the state is being overwritten as soon as something is typed in. Or something else which isn't apparent.

If it helps here is my state for the EssCrit1 textfield and it's accompanying character counter:

```
EssCrit1:null,
EssCrit1Count: null,
```

Comment: can you share full code?

Comment: Which bits do you need?

Comment: are you sure you are referring the right count state property? seems like it should be this.state.EssCrit1Count because of ${evt.target.name}Count`. Instead of value={this.state.EssCritChars1

Comment: Yes I tried that but no difference. I've edited my question above to what the code is now.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with setState. try this.setState(prevState => ({... prevState, ...obj})). If Its the only state you have you can simply this.setState(obj)

Comment: That seems to have worked. I've applied it to all textfields and their associated character counter textfields are now counting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Went with:

```
public handleChange = (evt: any) => {
  const {value} = (evt.target as any);
  const countKey = `${evt.target.name}Count`;
  const obj = {
    [evt.target.name]: value,
    [countKey]: value.toString().length,
  };
  this.setState(prevState => ({prevState, ...obj}));
 }
```

and for the render:

```
<td><TextField
     name="EssCrit1"
     value={this.state.EssCrit1}
     onChange={this.handleChange}
     multiline rows={2}
     />
     </td>
     <td ><TextField 
     name="EssCrit1Count"
     value={this.state.EssCrit1Count}
     disabled={true}               
     />
     </td>
```

Matched up the text 'Count' at the end of the const CountKey variable assignment from the handler with the states that required it. The main issue was the updating of the states. I changed this to

`this.setState(prevState => ({prevState, ...obj}));`

from

`this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, newState });`

which encompasses the changes detailed in the handler. Hope this helps someone. I'm going to reverse engineer what I have learnt from the magnificent help I've received. Thank you to everyone as always.