# How to handle a different type of event with a handler, specifically a dropdown and not a textfield. SPFX/React

Tags: reactjs

This is a continuation on from:
[How to create a handler function which 'handles' multiple textfields but also character counter textfields as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59664868/how-to-create-a-handler-function-which-handles-multiple-textfields-but-also-ch?noredirect=1#comment105489362_59664868)

I now want to use this handler to 'handle' a drop down along with textfields. I have this so far:

```
public handleChange = (evt: any) => {
   const {value} = (evt.target as any);
   const obj = {  
     [evt.target.name]: value, 
   };
  this.setState(prevState => ({prevState, ...obj}));
}
```

Which works for textfields.

I now want it to handle a Dropdown component from `office-ui-fabric`. I've tried creating a completely different handler like this:

```
public onDropDownChange = (evt: any) => {
  const {value} = (evt.target as any);
  this.setState({ value: evt.target.value});
}
```

The above, experimental, onDropDownChange does not work. It gives an error saying value does not exist on event. I'm fairly sure this is because whatever is returned from a drop down is not 'value' and could quite well be 'item'.
I could write a function specifically for this drop down but I'm trying to cut down the amount of code written using handlers.

JSX:

```
<Dropdown

     selectedKey={this.state.SelectedJobPlanDD}
     placeholder="Select..."
     onChange={this.onDropDownChange}
     options={jobPlanDDOptions}
     defaultSelectedKey={this.state.JobPlanDD}

   />
```

State:

```
SelectedJobPlanDD: undefined,
JobPlanDD: null,
```

BTW: If I log the change of the drop down I get undefined, so that's the start of the problem.

Also, here is a 'standalone' function that I've used in the past for drop downs, it may help:

```
private _dropDownFunction = (item: IDropdownOption) => {
    this.setState({ SelectedItem: (item && item.key) ? item.key.toString() : null })
```

Any idea what I could use? My understanding of event handlers and ultimately basic JS logic is limited, but I learn a great deal from any advice given on SO.

UPDATE: From LevelGlow's answer I've been able to return the selected item from the drop down. I'm using this for the handler:

```
public onDropDownChange = (evt: any, item) => {
  // const {item} = (evt.target as any);
  console.log(evt+'evt with text');
  console.log(evt); // THIS IS THE ONE THAT SHOWS THE SELECTED ITEM!
  console.log(item.text+'item.text with text'); //Shows undefined
  console.log(item); //shows 3 (I guess this is id of the item)
  console.log(item.key+'item.key with text'); //shows undefined.

  this.setState({ 

  });

}
```

Now I'm not sure how I'd implement this into the handler to update the state item.

Comment: typo ```evt.target.value```  not ```event.target.value```?

Comment: Corrected, still doesn't work. There is nothing to distinguish a drop down from a textfield is there? For example a textfield can have a 'name' property but a dd can't. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: please share jsx code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the selected item from the `Dropdown`, structure the `Dropdown`'s `onChange` handler as the [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/dropdown) say, example below:

```
public onDropDownChange = (evt, item) => {
    console.log(item.key);
    console.log(item.text);
};
```

The `onChange` event here has a DOM object as target which stores only the `text` of the dropdown and it can be accessed by

```
evt.target.querySelector('span').innerText;
```

You can add the `id` prop to your `Dropdown`:

```
<Dropdown
  id="JobPlanDD"
  ...
/>
```

Now the component generates a new `id` for you in the previously mentioned `span` tag and you can access it by calling

`evt.target.querySelector('span').id;` which returns `"JobPlanDD-option"`
And we will be using it as `key` for the `state`.

So your `selectedKey` should be:

```
selectedKey={(this.state["JobPlanDD-option"]) ? (this.state["JobPlanDD-option"]).key : undefined}
```

What this line doing is: do we have `JobPlanDD-option` in out state? if yes, we'll pass the `JobPlanDD-option` item's key to `selectedKey`, if we don't, we'll pass `undefined`.

Structure your shared handler like this:

```
public handleChange = (evt: any, item): void => {
  if(evt.target.value){
    //handle textfields here
  } else {
    //handle dropdowns here
    const id = evt.target.querySelector('span').id; //get the span's id
    //update state with the generated id and the selected option
    this.setState({ [id] : item }); 
  }
}
```

Since we updated the shared handler, we should update also how `TextField`s are calling it:

```
<TextField
  onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, null)}
  ...
/>
```

Now both text fields and dropdowns should work with this shared handler.

Comment: @Tom Can you provide a working(same error) code snippet? I'm trying but I need to know where does your `Dropdown` come from, `react-bootstrap`/`semantic-ui` or else? What's the initial values of your state? Is there anyway you could create a live example?

Comment: Hi, it's an MS Fabric UI DropDown: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/dropdown
Initial value of state is undefined, and null as above.

Comment: As you can see in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-elbakyan-c5kpp) the `Dropdown` event's `target` is a DOM object, add a second parameter to the `onChangeHandler` and that is the `IDropdownOption` object you are looking for.

Comment: Hi @leverglowh - I've updated the code which is allowing me to return the selected item in the drop down. Not sure how to implement that in the handler.

Comment: Does adding item as parameter to the shared handler work? Check if `evt.target.value` exists, if not use `item`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205950/discussion-between-leverglowh-and-tom).

Comment: sorry, I'm getting an error if I delete the text completely in any of the text fields that this handleChange function uses.

Comment: leverglowh suggested changing the if(evt.target.value) to 
if(evt.target.name) as this avoids the error.